# Delete form with checkbox doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to get a checkbox form to delete entries from the database/ftp server but I just can't get the delete button to delete something. Probably because I'm missing out on something as the error reporting keeps telling that the variable delete isn't determined but I can't find why it says that.

This is my code,

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Get our database connector
require("includes/conn.php");
?>
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY ID";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Selecteer welke auto('s) verkocht zijn</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Foto</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Merkt/Type</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Beschrijving</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
                    echo "<p>";
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo "<img src=\"content/uploads/" . $rows['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"125\" width=\"200\" /><br />" . "<br />"; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['fname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['lname']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
     echo "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Another problem I'm having with that code is that I want it to delete the image from the FTP too, not only the file name entry in the database.

<sup>P.S. I know about MySQL being deprecated, I'm going edit that after I have the script working like I want it too. Didn't have the time yet to take a look at PDO and MySQLi.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){ // Check delete button is clicked
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){ // loop only checked items and delete
   $sql = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id='$del_id'"; 
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
}
?>
```

and also what ever your logic you have written for delete move to the top of the page before the html code for your desired output.

Comment: gives me a page that keeps refreshing and still a Undefined index: delete message from error reporting

Comment: delete function works and no problem with the undefined index now but still it keeps refreshing, is there a way to make it refresh only once instead of keep refreshing?

Comment: remove the line echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">"; and also move the delete code top of the page just before html code

Comment: sorry move the delete code that just before the select query!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use variable delete although it's not declared.

Try with

```
<?php

    // Check if delete button active, start this 
    if($_POST['delete']){
       // Delete the record
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: i edited with your code resulting into this:

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 

if($_POST['delete']){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_multiple.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>

but still the same results: 
Notice: Undefined index: delete in /sites/mianautoservice.nl/www/delete_multiple.php on line 55

Comment: You need to wrap the <input name="delete"> in to form with a post method